# how to loop OR WHERE in codeigniter according to the data selected on MULTISELECT

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a data filter feature using the MULTISELECT category where the data that appears is in accordance with the list of categories selected on the filter. So, I plan to loop the OR WHERE command according to the list of categories chosen by the user. OR WHERE has been successfully loop according to the number of categories chosen, but not for the ID. And show error like this "Array to string conversion"

What is the cause and what is the solution? Thank you

---

### My Controller

```
$sort = $this->input->post('sort');
$category = $this->input->post("get_kategori_acara_css[]");
$interest = $this->input->post("get_interest_acara_css[]");

/* eksekusi library pagination ke model penampilan data */
if (!empty($sort) || !empty ($category) || !empty ($interest))
{ 
  $this->data['list_acara'] = $this->Acara_model->get_filtered($sort, $category, $interest, $config['per_page'], $dari);
}
else 
{
  $this->data['list_acara'] = $this->Acara_model->get_all_arsip();
}
```

### MY MODEL

```
public function get_filtered ($sort, $category, $interest) {
$this->db->join('kategori', 'acara.id_kategori = kategori.id_kategori');
$this->db->join('interest_acara ', 'acara.id_acara  = interest_acara.id_acara', 'left');
$this->db->join('hits_acara  ', 'acara.judul_seo = hits_acara.judul_seo', 'left');
$this->db->where('publish','Ya');
$this->db->group_by('acara.judul_seo');
if(!empty($sort AND empty($category) AND empty($interest))) 
{
  $this->db->order_by($sort, $this->order);
}
elseif(!empty($sort) AND !empty($category) AND empty($interest)) 
{
  foreach ($category as $value) {
    $this->db->or_where('acara.id_kategori', $value->id_kategori);
  }
}
return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
}
```

---

[Shown Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqizc.png)

[My Multiselect Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96tpd.png)

Comment: What is the value of `$category` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the use of `$value->id_kategori` in the `foreach ($category as $value)` loop.

The variable `$value` is not an object so trying to get the value of the property, i.e. `$value->id_kategori` makes no sense.

`$category` is a simple indexed array of values e.g.

```
array('0'=>'123', '1'=>'456', '2'=>'789')
```

I think all you need to do is change this

```
$this->db->or_where('acara.id_kategori', $value->id_kategori);
```

to this

```
$this->db->or_where('acara.id_kategori', $value);
```

Comment: WOW. your suggest It's working for me, Mister. Your explanation it's really helped me too. 

So, thank you very much for your help !!